# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'thread'" Error while committing in Kaggle

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, kernel, kaggle

I'm getting the following error when I try to commit on Kaggle.

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1944, in shutdown h.flush() File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/logging/__init__.py", line 882, in flush self._current_handler.flush() File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/logging/__init__.py", line 776, in flush self.stream.flush() File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/iostream.py", line 341, in flush if self.pub_thread.thread.is_alive(): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'thread'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that one of your objects makes an action `myObj.thread`, but this `myObj` is not initialized or has `myObj = None` or something like this. That is why you got the message `'NoneType' object ...`. You need to check object initialization or it assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an `ipykernel` related issue that has an [upstream fix](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/pull/463) which hasn't been packaged into a release yet. So you might have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote something like `y = x.thread` or `x.thread()` The problem is, `x` was `None`. `None` doesn't have a member variable named "`thread`"